# Convergence to unique limit point in $L^p_{\mathbb C}(\lambda)$.

Tags: real-analysis

Let $f,g, f_n \in L^p_{\mathbb C}(\lambda)$ and let $|| f ||$ denote the corresponding norm belonging to this vector space of equivalence classes.

How do I see that if $|| [f] - [f_n] ||_p \rightarrow 0$ for $n \rightarrow \infty$ and $|| [g] - [f_n] ||_p \rightarrow 0$ for $n \rightarrow \infty$ then it holds that $[f] = [g]$, that is a convergent sequence in $L^p_{\mathbb C}(\lambda)$ has a unique limit point ?

Answer (score 1):

If you know that $\|\cdot\|_p$ is a norm, then you can use the triangle inequality as follows.
$$
\begin{align}
\|[g]-[f]\|_p & = \|[g] - [f_n] + [f_n] - [f]\|_p \\
& \leq \|[g] - [f_n]\|_p + \|[f_n] - [f]\|_p.
\end{align}
$$
Here, we can make the r.h.s. arbitrarily small by choosing $n$ large enough. Thus, we conclude
$$
\|[g]-[f]\|_p = 0.
$$
By definition of norm, this implies
$$
[g] - [f] = 0,\qquad or\ equivalently\qquad [g] = [f],
$$
as desired.